# Charge plugin thanks page 404

Tags: redirect, plugin-charge

I keep getting the 404 after successful payment.

I am pretty sure I have everything set up correctly, the thanks template is there, but it seems like Craft won't respond to the request, so the routing is not trigged, Apache is still trying to serve that file directly, it won’t recognize the {hash} part in the URL, so keep return the 404 page.

The only way I find to make this work is manually add another redirect in the Route section (last screenshot), but it's not a nature way.

Any insight would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `slug` try using `*` in your route definition